# como hacer un triangulo con este simbolo en python (*)?

Tags: python, string, function, math

1) Mi primer problema es como aplicar la matemática con el símbolo (*) en forma str.

2) Mi segundo problema es como hago para que formen un triangulo como este

```
*
**
***
****
*****
```

Este es mi codigo hasta el momento

```
def triangulo():

    simbolo='*'

      for i in range(5):

         simbolo+=simbolo

         print(simbolo)

triangulo()
```

OUTPUT:

```
**

****

********

****************

********************************
```

Comment: te sugiero revisar esto: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15560730/asterisk-triangle-in-python

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Primero siguiendo tu ejemplo pero yo sin utilizar una función, declaras la variable simbolo que contendrá un *, después lo imprimes con print, creas el ciclo y aquí es lo importante para lograr lo que quieres: a la variable simbolo le concatenas otro * con el operador + y lo imprimes en cada iteración del ciclo for.

```
simbolo = '*'
print(simbolo)
for i in range(5):
   simbolo = simbolo + '*'
   print(simbolo)
```

Answer (score 4):

Lo que sucede es que en esta linea de tu código

```
simbolo += simbolo
```

Para cada iteracion estas concateando el valor anterior que tenia la variable simbolo y luego esta es reemplazada por el nuevo valor. Lo que ocasiona ese efecto de caracteres en potencias de a 2. Es decir empiezas con un solo caracter de '*' (2^0), en la primera iteracion son 2 (2^1), en la segunda iteracion 4 (2^2), en la tercera son 8 (2^3) y así sucesivamente.

Mi sugerencia es que aproveches la operación de multiplicación entre cadenas de texto y un numero de esta forma:

```
simbolo = '*'
for i in range(6):
    print(simbolo * i)
```