# ¿Cómo hago este triángulo en Python SOLO con ciclos for?

Tags: python, bucle-for, bucles, matrices, fórmulas-de-matriz

Efectuar un programa que solicite al usuario que ingrese un número
entero impar (validar el valor ingresado). El programa tendrá que
dibujar en la pantalla un triángulo de asteriscos cuya base sea el
valor ingresado.
Ejemplo:
Ingrese número: 8
Número no válido. Ingrese número: 11

```
      *          
    * * *        
  * * * * *      
* * * * * * *
```

---

---

Por ahora solo tengo esto:

```
num = int(input("Ingrese un número entero impar: "))
while num%2==0:
    num = int(input("Incorrecto. Ingrese un número entero impar: "))

for i in range(num+1):
    for j in range(num//2+1):
        if j<=num//2-i or j<=num//2+i or i==num//2:
            print("*")
        else:
            print(" ")
```

Cosa que me imprime la cantidad de asteriscos que necesito pero todo el una linea, falta ordenarlos. Cómo podría ordenar los asteriscos paraque me formen el triángulo?

nota: la condición del if la saqué de esta matriz:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ya vi una pregunta sobre dibujar un triángulo. Si alguien las encuentrá será cerrada por duplicado.

Comment: @Mateo. Eso dice mucho de la búsqueda en este sitio.

Comment: Estas dos preguntas te pueden ayudar a resolver el problema. [Dibujar un triángulo con asteriscos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/202156/169744) y [Dibujar un rombo con asteriscos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/351365/169744). Si logras resolverlo con ayuda de ellas elimina la pregunta para no tener que hacerlo nosotros por vos.

Comment: Hay algo que puede parecer que las respuestas no tuvieron en cuenta pero nunca aclaras, ¿Es importante que los asteriscos tengan espacios en medio?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Respecto a la cantidad de astericos pude observar que tu código no funcionaba como se espera.

En primer lugar se pide al usuario que base de asteriscos desea tener para formar la pirámide, siendo como requisito que este sea impar. Tal como lo tienes en tu código se encuentra bien y no hay necesidad de cambiar algo

```
# Pedimos al usuario el número de la base de asteriscos que desea
num = int(input("Ingrese un número entero impar: "))
while num%2==0:
  num = int(input("Incorrecto. Ingrese un número entero impar: "))
```

Después de esto, procedemos a la construcción de la pirámide. Para este caso decidí realizarlo mediante la aproximación que indicaste en la pregunta, y para esto se recorre una matriz "imaginaria" tal que donde no es necesario poner un asterisco, simplemente ubica un espacio. El siguiente diagrama puede ayudarte a entenderlo mejor:

[image: Diagrama respecto a la construcción de pirámide]

Para recorrer esta matriz, definimos las siguientes variables y el siguiente for anidado:

```
# Número de filas en la matriz
n = (num//2)+1
# Número de columnas en la matriz
num

for i in range(n):
  for j in range(num):
    if ((j>=(num//2)-i) and (j<=(num//2)+i)):
      print("*",end='')
    elif (j==num-1):
      print("")
    else:
      print(' ',end='')
```

Lo que realiza el anterior for anidado es evaluar si respecto a un espacio de la matriz debe de haber un asterisco o un espacio. La fórmula encargada de evaluar esto es la siguiente:`(j>=(num//2)-i) and (j<=(num//2)+i)` y en caso de que la anterior condición sea verdadera, agregará un asterisco, y si es falsa, agregará un espacio. Notese que para este ejemplo la función print consta de un parámetro *end*, que indica a la consola no terminar con un salto de linea.

Por último, si la fila ya ha sido recorrida en su totalidad por *j*, el código tiene en cuenta esto con la condición: `(j==num-1)`, haciendo que la consola imprima un salto de línea y así pueda seguir con la siguiente fila de asteriscos.

El código completo es el siguiente:

```
# Pedimos al usuario el número de la base de asteriscos que desea
num = int(input("Ingrese un número entero impar: "))
while num%2==0:
    num = int(input("Incorrecto. Ingrese un número entero impar: "))

# Número de filas en la matriz
n = (num//2)+1
# Número de columnas en la matriz
num

for i in range(n):
  for j in range(num):
    if ((j>=(num//2)-i) and (j<=(num//2)+i)):
      print("*",end='')
    elif (j==num-1):
      print("")
    else:
      print(' ',end='')
```

Comment: Hola, @Seb0927. Tu código me resultó muy sencillo de comprender porque lo explicaste excelente. El único inconveniente que estoy encontrando es el de que, a la hora de que el IDLE me imprima el triángulo, me queda como que muy junto, es decir, le falta imprimir espacios delante de los asteríscos. Cómo se podría aumentar la cantidad de espacios en blanco que se imprimen delante de cada fila de asteríscos? Si eso se pudiese solucionar, el código sería perfecto.

Comment: @AGUS En ese caso, solo necesitas añadir un espacio a la izquierda del astersico, y un espacio en el print del else.

Answer (score 3):

Una función que recibe el ancho de la base de la piramide y la imprime

```
def piramide(base: int):
    mitad = base // 2
    for i in range(mitad + 1):
        print(' ' * (mitad - i) + '*' * (2*i + 1))
```

En cada línea simplemente se calcula el número de espacios a la izquierda, seguido del número de astericos.

#### Demo

```
piramide(11)
```

produce:

```
     *
    ***
   *****
  *******
 *********
***********

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Lo bueno, si breve, dos veces bueno, +1.

Comment: Hola! Tu función está genial, súper concisa y al punto. El tema es que tiene el mismo inconveniente que la de @Seb0927: el triangulo queda como muy junto y le faltan imprimirse asteríscos delante de cada línea. Es raro, como que la cantidad de espacios delante de cada línea es siempre par, va disminuyendo de a dos (es decir, suponiendo que el número sea 11, la primera línea va a tener 8 espacios y despues un asterísco, la segunda 6 espacios y después tres asteríscos y así hasta que se imprime la base entera). Pero el tema es que no sé como hacer eso tampoco, vos tenes alguna idea?

Comment: @Agus. Es cosa que reemplaces `'*'` por `'* '`.

Comment: Si, y agregarle otro espacio al espacio en blanco. Ahí pude, gracias :D

Answer (score 0):

```
num = int( input( "Ingrese un número entero impar: " ))
while num % 2 == 0:
    num = int( input( "Incorrecto. Ingrese un número entero impar: " ))
    
cantidadFilas = num // 2 + 1
largoPalabra = cantidadFilas -1
largoSubPalabra = -1

for i in range( cantidadFilas ):
    largoPalabra += 1
    largoSubPalabra += 2
    textoParaImprimir = ""
    for i in range( largoPalabra ):
        if( i < largoPalabra - largoSubPalabra  ):
            textoParaImprimir  += "-"
        else:
           textoParaImprimir += "*"  
    
    print( textoParaImprimir )
```

Como verás, es un enfoque un poco distinto a la excelente respuesta de @Seb0927.
Con **largoPalabra** obtengo la longitud de la palabra, osea la cuenta de los **" "** más los **"*"**.
Con **largoSubPalabra** determino la cantidad de **"*"** que tendrá cada fila.
Dentro del primer for, actualizo **largoSubPalabra** y **largoPalabra** y creo **textoParaImprimir**.
En el segundo for, si las "i", son menores a la diferencia entre **largoSubPalabra** y **largoPalabra**, aggrego a **textoParaImprimir** un espacio en blanco, y si no, un asterísco.
Cada vez que se sale del for interno imprime, **textoParaImprimir**.